# Getting max post_year group by email

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Given the table below

```
Email  Post_Year
====== ==========
a@a.com  2007
a@a.com  2008
b@b.com  2009
b@b.com  2010
```

I want to have results with max Post_year group by email

```
Email  Post_Year
====== ==========
a@a.com  2008
b@b.com  2010
```

This code does not work since `[Post_Year]` is not aggregate operation in the `having` portion

```
SELECT TOP (1000) *
  FROM [DataExtraction2].[dbo].[Users]
group by [Email]
having max([Post_Year]) = [Post_Year]
```

How to achieve the purpose?

Comment: include email and max(postyear) in `select` and remove the `having` and `top` from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get just the email and post year, then simply use aggregation:

```
Select email, max(post_year)
From [DataExtraction2].[dbo].[Users]
Group by email;
```

If you have more columns to get and you want to get all the rows with maximum post_year for each email, use window function `max`:

```
Select *
From (
  Select t.*,
  Rank() over (partition by email order by post_year desc) rn
  From [DataExtraction2].[dbo].[Users] t
) t where rn = 1
```

If you want to get only one row (any) for each email with max post_year, use `row_number` instead:

```
Select *
From (
  Select t.*,
  row_number() over (partition by email order by post_year desc) rn
  From [DataExtraction2].[dbo].[Users] t
) t where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! The one I needed is the second one, with row_number() rather than rank() :) I have a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325221/getting-max-post-year-group-by-email-with-num-of-years
Can help take a look? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sweetyBaby - As per the description of your problem *"max Post_year group by email"*, rank made more sense to me as it gets all the rows with max year. I originally answered it with row_number and changed it later to rank. Anyways, glad it worked for you. I've updated the answer. :-)