# Getting max post_year group by email with num of years

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Given the table below

```
Email  Post_Year  country
====== ========== =======
a@a.com  2006       US
a@a.com  2007       US
a@a.com  2008       HK1
a@a.com  2008       HK
b@b.com  2009       CN
b@b.com  2010       SW
```

I want to have

1. all columns with max Post_year group by email, if there are multiple max Post_year, just choose one
2. as well as the num_of_yrs which is max(post_year)-min(post_year) of that particular email.

> ```
> Email  Post_Year  country  Num_Of_Yrs
> ====== ========== ======= =============
> a@a.com  2008      HK       2 [which is 2008-2006]
> b@b.com  2010      SW       1 [which is 2010-2009]
> ```

How to achieve the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Edited: With your edited intention, you could simply use:

```
SELECT 
    email, 
    MAX(post_year) post_year,
    MAX(country) country, 
    MAX(post_year) - MIN(post_year) num_of_yrs
FROM 
    table_name
GROUP BY 
    email;
```

You could use this:

```
WITH tmp AS
(
    SELECT 
        email, 
        MAX(post_year) max_post_year,
        MIN(post_year) min_post_year
    FROM 
        table_name
    GROUP BY 
        email
)
SELECT 
    t.email,
    t.post_year,
    t.country,
    tmp.max_post_year - tmp.min_post_year num_of_yrs
FROM 
    table_name t
INNER JOIN 
    tmp
ON t.email = tmp.email
    AND t.post_year = tmp.max_post_year;
```

Comment: thanks, but there is a possibility of multiple max post year, and in this case I would choose one randomly, I have modified the question to reflect this, what should we do in this case?

Comment: @sweetyBaby with multiple max post_year, which country do you want in your result set?

Comment: randomly choose one

Comment: @sweetyBaby If that's your intention, you could simply use the GROUP BY statement like in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function row_number to get one row with max year per email and window functions max and min to get max difference for each email.

Try this:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by email 
                            order by post_year desc) rn,
        max(post_year) over (partition by email) -
        min(post_year) over (partition by email) num_of_yrs
    from your_table t
    ) t where rn = 1;
```